# How use react-query mutations with axios?

Tags: react-query

I'm trying to use [react-query mutations](https://react-query.tanstack.com/docs/guides/mutations) using axios but when my request return an http error my `catch()` is not being called.

This is what i tried:

```
const BannerRightConfirmEmail = () => {
  const [{ token }] = useState<ITokenConfirmationEmailParam>(useParams());
  const [mutateConfirmEmail] = useMutation(confirmEmailUser);

  useEffect(() => {
    confirmEmail();
  }, []);

  const confirmEmail = async () => {
    try {
      await mutateConfirmEmail(token);
    } catch (errorReq) {
      console.log(errorReq);
    }
  };
```

my **user.service.ts**:

```
const confirmEmailUser = async (token: string) => {
  await api.patch('/users/confirmEmail/' + token)
}

export { confirmEmailUser }
```

**my api.ts:**

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:3100",
});
```

My request is returning a 400 error status, but nothing is being printed in my `catch()`, why?

Comment: Did you find solution? I have same problem.

Comment: @Dirk yes, you need to use the onSuccess/onError event of the mutation, see this component that use mutations: https://github.com/veronesecoms/react-chat-front/blob/master/src/pages/home/Header/Header.tsx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mutate function handles the exception so the catch block will never run. You can handle errors using the `onError` handler function that can be set on the hook or mutate function level. For instance:

```js
const [
   mutate,
   { status, isIdle, isLoading, isSuccess, isError, data, error, reset },
 ] = useMutation(mutationFn, {
   onError(err, variables, onMutateValue) {
      // error handling logic
      // fires after the mutate-level handler
   }
 })
const promise = mutate(variables, {
   onError(err, variables, onMutateValue) {
      // error handling logic
      // fires before the hook-level handler
   }
 })
```

As an alternative you can also move the error handling logic inside the `mutationFn` passed to `useMutation` like this:

```js
const confirmEmailUser = async (token: string) => {
  let response;
  try {
    response = await api.patch('/users/confirmEmail/' + token)
  } catch (errorReq) {
    console.log(errorReq);
  }
  return response;
}

export { confirmEmailUser }
```

This way you can handle the error before it reaches `react-query`